# How to Lock multiple tables for Insert command in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, client-server

[image]

This is my table Structure

When I insert Data into the first table, it will have multiple entries in table 2
I am Using code
To Get ID

```
Select MAX(ID)+1 From Table1
```

To Insert Data

```
    Insert Into Table1 Values('1','abc','add1');
    Insert into table2 values('1','med','english');
    Insert into table2 values('1','eng','english');
```

Code is working fine for single computer but when we used in application in multiple terminals it is inserting wrong data i.e. data of another id in table2

Comment: dont use `MAX(ID)+1` instead of it use `identity(1,1)` on table

Comment: My problem is not with first table it is with second table when application used in lan data gets mixed with another entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need ensure that the ID column of table1 is an identity column and then do the following:

```
DECLARE @ID INT

INSERT table1 ([columns])
VALUES (...)

SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT table2 (table1ID, [columns])
VALUES (@ID, ...)
```

You can read more about SCOPE_IDENTITY() [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql).

`MAX(ID)` will include ID values created by other processes, which is why your second insert is mixing up data.

Comment: This will work if the SCOPE_IDENTITY() is called from the same scope. If not @@IDENTITY should be used.

Comment: You need to be careful with @@IDENTITY as values inserted by triggers can interfere with its value.